# How to get the Vista taskbar to span multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-vista, taskbar

I can't for the life of me get the vista taskbar to span multiple monitors.

I've searched and looked far and wide, and alas the only pseudo-solution i can find is Ultra-Mon, but a) it doesn't quite look the same  and b) i don't want to have to pay for something that Windows really ought to be able to do out of the box.

Does anyone have a solution for this?  Will this get addressed in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Multi-Mon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) as a free alternative to Ultra-Mon.

Comment: It's a shame it isn't skinned to the OS without paying for it.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 7 doesn't have a multi-monitor taskbar. However, [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/)** does. It's inexpensive, has full Windows 7 compatibility and a ton of other multi-monitor features as well (mouse shortcuts, hotkeys, titlebar buttons... etc). :)

(**I'm probably biased, because I'm the developer)

Comment: @Jon: Please add task grouping to the secondary taskbar! This feature has been in windows taskbars since XP, it's essential for people like me who have many windows open from the same app. I've tried like 5 different "taskbar on second monitor" apps, and none of them do it for some reason! Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an nvidia graphics card you can specify that you want the task bar to span two screens in the nview manager.

Answer (score -1):

From what it looks like, **[yes](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2008/10/microsoft-talks-multimonitor-taskbar-support-in-windows-7.ars)** it will be fixed in Windows 7.

Comment: The RC of Windows 7 didn't have a multi-monitor taskbar, so I assume the RTM version won't either. This article was speculation from 2008 before the first public release.