# Extend laptop to TV, but Nvidia and Windows only shows one display

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, windows-vista, nvidia-geforce

I have an Alienware M17x laptop with two Nvidia GeForce GTX 280M video cards.

How do I extend my laptop display to my Samsung TV?

I wasn't able to do it via Nvidia or Windows settings. I followed the instructions but couldn't use either. Nvidia only offers me single display.

Can someone come up with a step-by-step solution please?

Comment: If you are running Linux, what does `xrandr` output?

Comment: Try looking over the multiple-monitors tag, that might help you out a bit. There are quite a lot of questions related to this: http://superuser.com/questions/9034/multi-monitor-usage, http://superuser.com/questions/2286/monitor-utilities, http://superuser.com/questions/3004/what-is-the-best-multiple-monitors-app-for-windows-7.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I am using windows vista 64 bit, 

i wonder whether it is a software problem (nvidia control panel) because it only shows me the single display (under menu set up multiple displays).

whats the latest driver or software from nvidia ? let me know thanks

Comment: I suggest you try to plug before all the TV to your laptop, then start your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Essential in this case is to plug cable to the TV, then 'tell' TV to get signal (source) from proper cable (it would be vga or hdmi - it depend how u connected it) than if nothing  automaticly happens You must switch displays on computer (ussually its 'Fn' + f2)

Standard options are: only external, only main screen or both (clone view or extended)

Comment: using windows 7 you can toggle these options using WinKey+P combo