# Is there a way to duplicate the taskbar across multiple monitors in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I don't want to expand it.

I want to duplicate it on both, keeping the expanded desktop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) or [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) is what you want.

Not sure about MultiMon, but UltraMon has an option to "mirror" the taskbar on the other monitor:

[image: UltraMon Options Screenshot]

Also:

> [How to get the Vista taskbar to span multiple monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/1872/how-to-get-the-vista-taskbar-to-span-multiple-monitors)

Comment: But I don't want to **expand** it

Comment: Thanks for the Multimon reference. I've been looking for a freeware application

Comment: oh, ok         .

Comment: I think you would need to use one of the newer beta version of Ultramon for it work correctly in Win7

Comment: I doesn't replicate the notification icons, and I wanted it for this =(