# duplicate taskbar on 2 monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, shortcuts

I've just got a new computer monitor, and I've added it to my previous one, and I have some questions I need answers to:

1. Is there any way to make the windows taskbar go on both monitors? I tried using DispleyFusion (5.1), but after installation it didn't work and after a few reinstalls it just gave a BSoD.
2. Is there a way to make a shortcut button on my mouse/keyboard to make the mouse pointer jump to the other monitor?

Comment: What are you running? Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1 / Mac / Linux ?

Comment: #1 is possible with third-party software and out of the box on Windows 8. #2 just drag your mouse its not that much effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Vista taskbar to span multiple monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/1872/how-to-get-the-vista-taskbar-to-span-multiple-monitors), http://superuser.com/questions/43252/how-do-i-get-the-windows-7-taskbar-with-the-start-menu-to-display-on-dual-monito?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/22273/is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-the-taskbar-across-multiple-monitors-in-windows-7?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/217720/mirroring-windows-7-taskbar-on-multiple-displays?lq=1

Comment: What's the body of your question got to do with "Extra monitor won't work properly"?

Comment: BTW: I've been using DisplayFusion for many years now on multiple computers.  I run the latest version 5.1(.1) currently, and I've *never* had it cause a BSoD on me (even when running the beta versions).  Personally, I'd be concerned about that first. :(

Answer (score -3):

Please follow these steps and it will address both issues:

1. Right Click + Screen Resolution on Desktop on First Monitor
2. Select Duplicate Desktop on 1 and 2 from Multiple Displays - DropDown Menu
3. Select Apply
4. Again Right Click + Screen Resolution on Desktop on **Second Monitor**
5. This time select check box for "Make this my main display"
6. Select Apply

This would make task bar appear on both the screens and Mouse moves from screen1 to screen2 automatically [Just keep moving your mouse to your right and it will appear on the screen2].

Note: you need to select "Make this my main display" on the second monitor.

Comment: doesn't work, sorry. after duplicating there isn't any "Make this my main display" check box.

Comment: I did repeat the steps on Windows7 and I see the option, Please Right Click + Screen Resolution on Desktop on **Second Monitor**, this option would not come on first monitor. hope this helps.